# How to Install visual studio add in for U2 toolkit for .NET v1.3.0

Tags: visual-studio, u2netdk

I got the Install for .Net Provider 1.3.0, Even after installing 64 bit version, I could not get visual studio add in for U2, so that I can choose ".Net Framework Provider for U2 Database" when adding data source.

Most of the questions over web says "Download and Install U2NETDK v1.2.0 BETA" back in 2012. Is there something different for 1.3.0 to get the add in ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:
1) There is a new version of U2 Toolkit for .NET v 2.1.0
2) The documentation for it is here: http://www.rocketsoftware.com/brand/rocket-u2/u2-toolkit-net-v210-technical-documentation

3) If you really need to stick with v1.3.0 the doc is here: http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/ search under Rocket U2, U2 Toolkit for .NET, Previous versions.

and finally and maybe most importantly

The add-ins you are looking for are part of U2 Toolkit for .NET Developer which is a chargeable product. You should talk to your Rocket software provider (ISV/VAR/Distributor) to find out how to obtain the Developer product.  If you aren't sure who to talk to, email u2bc@rs.com to find out.

Answer (score 2):

For U2 Toolkit for .NET v2.1.0 Developer/U2 Visual Studio Add-ins, you will see the following.

[image]

This installer installs 3 components:

1. 32-bit Provider (silently)
2. 64-bit Provider (silently)
3. Developer or U2 Visual Studio Add-ins